# Remove Movies app action

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, movies

I try manage entitites in video.wants_to_watch, if this entities created in my app all ok. But if I added some movie from [facebook web page](https://www.facebook.com/me/movies), I can't remove them. I recieve this error:

```
"(#10) User cannot delete action"
```

In https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.wants_to_watch I see movies, what I added from [facebook web page](https://www.facebook.com/me/movies), created with "Movies" application. So the question is how I can delete action created in Movies app with my custom app.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot as is the case with any object added that is **not** added by your application.

e.g. you cannot delete pictures not posted from your application.

It's to prevent rogue apps running amok messing with data they don't own.

Comment: Yes, I understand. This is simple security. But perhaps there is a way to get the permission to control the actions created in another application. I talk about [user_actions:APP_NAMESPACE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/) permission. But this app (Movies) has no app namespace.

Comment: again, no. You can only control your own application.